# The paradox of Imbalanced binary classification ¿To do something or to do nothing?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, class-imbalance, multiclass-classification, multilabel-classification

**Context:** Suppose we are interested in deploy a machine learning model to solve a problem of binary classification; furthermore, assume that the dataset $\mathcal{D}$ for the training of our model suffers of class imbalance.

What I've heard in the literature is that I'm in trouble because a model trained over an imbalanced data would develop a statistical bias towards the class with more observations; that's a problem because we are not interested in learning the proportion of the data, the goal of ML (and ours) is to learn the hidden patterns of the data that cause one observation being in one class or the other.

**First Point of View (Do something!):** Class imbalance is a problem, but I can use one of the many existing techniques to deal with problem; from data/samplig-level, SMOTE-like methods, synthetic generation of data (by means of autoencoders, [GANs](https://sdv.dev/SDV/user_guides/single_table/ctgan.html)) etc.

**Reference:**

- [Imbalanced Data an extensive guide on how to deal with imbalanced classification problems](https://medium.com/eni-digitalks/imbalanced-data-an-extensive-guide-on-how-to-deal-with-imbalanced-classification-problems-6c8df0bc2cab)

**Second Point of View(Do nothing!):** On the other hand I've seen a lot people explicitly arguing that training a machine learning model over an imbalanced data does not, in principle, introduce any bias towards the class with more observations. What strongly alarms me is that the general advice of this viewpoint on how to deal with the problem of binary classification is .. Do nothing! Expose your model to the raw data as extracted from *real life*. Actually I've heard experts in credit fraud detection saying that this is, in fact, the way they deal with his problem.

**Reference:**

- [Your Dataset Is Imbalanced? Do Nothing!](https://towardsdatascience.com/your-dataset-is-imbalanced-do-nothing-abf6a0049813)

---

**Problem:** I know that the answer to the question *'What to do?'* completely depends on the problem in turn. My trouble is that I'm unable to find what features of the problem could give me some insight in which viewpoint I should adopt in a given case.

---

**Question:** ***Could you please point out some heuristics that would help me to identify when class imbalance is really a problem?***

Thanks in advance! (please feel free to criticize or refute anything I had written).

Comment: See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/357466/232706 and its Linked questions.

Comment: I would take any blog posts with some healthy skepticism.  That first one you linked says "most of the common machine learning algorithms fail since they are designed to improve accuracy" which is plainly false AFAIK.

Comment: @BenReiniger Thanks a lot for your kind comment and the very useful reference!